# In a joint distribution, is it true that $P(A_1, \dots A_n, A) = P(A_1, \dots A_n, A^{c})$ if $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

In general, if I have that $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n$, and define $N(A_i)$ as the elements in $A_i$, and have $N(A_1)+\dots+N(A_n) = N(A)$, is this always true?:

$$
P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A)=n] = P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n]
$$

My proof is the following:

\begin{align}
P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A)=n] 
= P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A\setminus\{A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n\})=0]= P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(\emptyset)=0]
\end{align}

Since the number of events in the empty is is always zero, it happens with probability 1 and since the number of elements in the empty set is independent of the rest,

\begin{align}
P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(\emptyset)=0] 
= P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n]P[N(\emptyset)=0] = P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n]
\end{align}

Comment: If the sets $A_i$ are disjoint and $n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$, then $$[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A)=n] = [N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n]$$ hence $$P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A)=n] = P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n].$$ If the sets $A_i$ are disjoint and $n\ne a_1+\cdots+a_n$, then $$[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A)=n] = \varnothing$$ hence, in general, $$P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n, N(A)=n] = 0\ne P[N(A_1)=a_1 , \dots, N(A_n)=a_n].$$

Comment: But please *change the title*...